# How to Set / Mock propety (C#, UnitTest)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq, fluent-assertions

I got this:

```
private List<NameValuePair<CarTemplateType>> m_tempCars
 
public IList<NameValuePair<CarTemplateType>> CarTypes
{
     get
     {
         if (m_tempCars == null)
         {
             //somelogic
         }

         return m_tempCars;
     }
}
```

`CarsVM` has `Init` where `m_tempCars` is being setup:

```
m_tempCars= CarTypes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == my_data.CarTypes);
```

Now I have `TestMethod`:

```
[TestMethod]
Public void SomeTest()
{
CarsVM cars = new CarsVM ();

cars.CarTypes = ??? //

...
}
```

How to somehow Mock/Set this?

Comment: which mocking-framework do you use? Usually you don't `new` your dependency yourself, but let the framework do this for you. Then you can use something like `cars.Setup(x => x.CarType).Returns(whatever)`. However be aware that you can only mock `virtual` or `abstract` members of your class.

Comment: Usually you don't mock concrete instances you just set them up correctly. Hence in this case you will need to set `my_data` to needed value so `m_tempCars` is set correctly.

Comment: TestPlatform => MSTest

Answer (score 1):

If you use Moq:

```
public class Car : ICar
    {
        public List<CarType> CarTypesList { get; set; }

        public List<CarType> GetCarTypes()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
    
    public interface ICar
    {
        public List<CarType> CarTypesList { get; set; }

        public List<CarType> GetCarTypes();
    }

    public class CarType
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    [Fact]
    public void TestCar()
    {
        Mock<ICar> carMock = new Mock<ICar>();
        carMock.Setup(x => x.CarTypesList).Returns(new List<CarType>());
        carMock.Setup(x => x.GetCarTypes()).Returns(new List<CarType>());
        
    }
```

You can generally make your code more testable by following SOLID principles. They will ensure that your code modules stay small, and easy to test and extend.

Comment: `CarTypes` is not a method rather than a property. Please fix your `Setup` accordingly. Also, it is not defined as `virtual` or `abstract` so I think your `Setup` or `SetupGet` will throw `NotSupportedException`.

Comment: @PeterCsala
This was heavy pseudo code, which I thought was obvious, but I have instead given an example that compiles and runs.